# How to navigate to reactJS subpage with Gecko and capture DocumentCompleted event

Tags: c#, reactjs, geckofx

I'm trying to access multiple websites one after the other and (based on some conditions) sometimes also dig deeper into the subpages of the site.

GeckoFX does not seem to support navigating to relative pages like `<a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>`, which I solved by attaching them to the URL of the page I'm already on, like `("http://www.example.com/" + "/imprint").Replace("//", "/")`.

Now I'm running into a problem with a (i guess reactJS?) page that supplies only URL fragments to navigate, e.g. `<a href="#imprint">Imprint</a>`. When I call `Navigate` directly on the full URL, e.g. `http://www.example.com/#imprint`, while I'm not already on the site, it works like expected and opens the right page.

But if I try to navigate to this subpage while I'm already on site, it either doesn't navigate at all or at least doesn't fire the DocumentCompleted event. I can't tell, the browser is entirely running in the background.

The way I understand it, react doesn't actually load a new site, but just refreshes some element of the same site via JavaScript, so it would make sense to not trigger the DocumentCompleted event. Is there any way to catch the finished document with the new content regardless or do I need to find a workaround, like navigating away first and then coming back or something like that?

**EDIT**: The problem also exists on jump markers e.g. if I try to navigate from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Data_types

I've built in a time limit for my browser to navigate to a site an trigger the DocumentCompleted event just so I don't get stuck on this problem anymore. However, the question persists, of course.